# Remove string from string contain specific

Tags: php

I need help with this:

```
string = 'Wednesday dynamic date';
```

Remove word that contain `day` means remove `Sunday`, `Monday`, `Tuesday`, `Wednesday`. 
Output i need is dynamic date.

Comment: try something, ask later.

Comment: Show you code please. What you tried made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `preg_replace` for that:

```
echo preg_replace("/\b[a-z]*day\b/i", '', "Wednesday dynamic date");

// output:

dynamic date
```

Comment: Please, **do not** answer to a VLQ questions, that shows no effort on OP side. This is against our idea. Such questions should be voted to close, not answered.

Comment: It certainly has! At least one from me! :> I don't know, why there is no trace of that. And, it should have at least one from you! :) Beside it has -6. And beside, I politely asked you (or remind you) about rules here. It doesn't change anything, that question hasn't been VTC, it is very low quality, lacks of any OP's work and should definitely be closed, not answered.

Comment: @kakkar I very appreciate _Justinas_ attempt to help you, but rules are rules. We don't answer here to questions that asks about very obvious problems, which can be solved by doing 30-seconds-Google and that has been answered hundred of times (even here -- your question is a direct duplicate of at least few here). I have nothing wrong personally to you. Everyone started his/her journey here at some point in time and everyone made many mistakes. Voting to close your question is not to punish you, but to keep this site out of repeated questions and other kind of "garbage".

Comment: @kakkar Keeping this site out of garbage **is** very productive. If you don't understand that, maybe you will understand this, when many of your next question will get many downvotes and will be closed. You want a link, to learn? Have you noticed "Help" button in the top? It leads you to [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), where you can learn anything. Especially: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And, please, stop calling me "inteligent", "instructor" or offending me in any other ways or I'll report you and you'll be banned from using this site.

Comment: @trejder Its a common problem with newcomers, they learn things with time. Also if you are so worried about this question why did you edited this question at first point. 
kakkar: You should first tell community about your approach so that people can help in a better way. Be Polite and helpful as all members here are same kind of people as you(Programmers)

Comment: @asachanfbd I edited it, because I somehow _automatically_ edit badly-formatted posts. I like tidy and clean posts. Only after edit I realised, that this question is actually to be closed as duplicate and showing no effort on OP's side.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
<?php $str = "Wednesday dynamic date";
//preg dynamic 
    echo preg_replace("/\b[a-z]*day\b/i", '', "Wednesday dynamic date");
//static
    echo str_ireplace("day","",$str );
    ?>
```

Comment: Please, **do not** answer to a VLQ questions, that shows no effort on OP side. This is against our idea. Such questions should be voted to close, not answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use regex like this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\w*day/is','','Wednesday dynamic date');
```

Comment: Please, **do not** answer to a VLQ questions, that shows no effort on OP side. This is against our idea. Such questions should be voted to close, not answered.

Comment: is this correctly solved your problem. if yes then marked correct as anyone who is looking for this type of question get helped.